# Question about Out and Return?

Tags: c#, .net

In this code (from the [WCF REST starterkit](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24644) - preview2):

```
protected override SampleItem OnAddItem(SampleItem initialValue, out string id)
        {
            // TODO: Change the sample implementation here
            id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            this.items.Add(id, initialValue);
            return initialValue;
        }
```

Am I getting back id as String, or the initialValue as SampleItem?

Edit:
Looks like I get both back, so what would a simple example of the method call look like assigned to a couple of variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get back id in the string that you pass as a parameter to the method. Also, the method will return the SampleItem instance.

```
SampleItem myItem = new SampleItem();
string newId = string.Empty;
myItem = OnAddItem(myItem, out newId);
// now myItem will be assigned with SampleItem returned from the
// OnAddItem method, and newId will be updated with the id assigned
// within that method
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting both.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting back both.

You will pass in a string variable for ID and that will be returned to you via the 'out' modifier. The function will also return the SampleItem instance initialValue that you passed in.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting back both. An `out` parameter is just an additional way to to return a value offered by some programming languages.